# Symfony 2 dependency injection into the Controller construct

Tags: php, symfony

I've tried to add many services into the construct of a Controller without success.

```
class PersonController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(UtilityService $Utils)
    {
        $this->util = $Utils;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

what's the path I must follow?

Comment: You need define your controller `PersonController` as a [service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Cerad mention in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106195/symfony-2-dependency-injection-di-of-controllers):

The trick is to define your controllers as services and then use the service id instead of the class name.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Comment: This is not a complete answer, you can not just insert a link to documentation

Comment: Also this just mentions another answer. Not really fair to @Victor

Comment: sorry if you think otherwise but I don't see the point to duplicate the answer. Even considering this is what he needs. It's clear, quickly and good enough for it purpose

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your `PersonController` controller as a service in `services.yml` and inject to them `UtilityService`:

```
# src/Acme/HelloBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
parameters:
    # ...
    person.controller.class: Acme\HelloBundle\Controller\PersonController

services:
    person.controller:
        class: "%person.controller.class%"
        arguments: ["@UtilityService"]
```

Where:

1. **person.controller.class** is a name of your controller class
2. **UtilityService** in `arguments` is a name of servicem which you want to inject